# How to insert the element in to list in shell

Tags: shell, sh

```
{
        "id": "123",
        "teamName": "Developers",
        "members": [
            {
                "name": "E",
                "fullName": null,
                "type": "ROLE",
                "roleId": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Managers",
                "fullName": null,
                "type": "ROLE",
                "roleId": ""
            }
        ],
        "permissions": [
            "template#edit",
            "trigger#view_trigger",
            "release#start",
            "release#reassign_task",
            "template#view",
            "folder#view",
            "template#create_release",
            "release#abort",
            "folder#edit",
            "release#view"
        ],
        "systemTeam": false


    }
```

I have this above json output from curl, want to insert another element in to that members block, see below, added the second element whose name key is F.

Expected output:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "teamName": "Developers",
    "members": [

        {
            "name": "E",
            "fullName": null,
            "type": "ROLE",
            "roleId": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "F",
            "fullName": null,
            "type": "ROLE",
            "roleId": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Managers",
            "fullName": null,
            "type": "ROLE",
            "roleId": ""
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "template#edit",
        "trigger#view_trigger",
        "release#start",
        "release#reassign_task",
        "template#view",
        "folder#view",
        "template#create_release",
        "release#abort",
        "folder#edit",
        "release#view"
    ],
    "systemTeam": false
},
```

{
"id": "123",
"teamName": "Managers",
"members": [

```
    {
        "name": "E",
        "fullName": null,
        "type": "ROLE",
        "roleId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "F",
        "fullName": null,
        "type": "ROLE",
        "roleId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Managers",
        "fullName": null,
        "type": "ROLE",
        "roleId": ""
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "template#edit",
    "trigger#view_trigger",
    "release#start",
    "release#reassign_task",
    "template#view",
    "folder#view",
    "template#create_release",
    "release#abort",
    "folder#edit",
    "release#view"
],
"systemTeam": false
```

}
}

I want to do this with in sh script, tried doing find and replace, but looks ugly.

Comment: Can you use jq? That would look roughly like `jq '.members = [.members[0], {name: "F", fullName: null, type: "ROLE", roleId: ""}] + .members[1:]'` or so.

Comment: @vimedit : _but looks ugly_ : I would still advise posting your attempt. Don't be shy showing ugly code. One purpose of this site is to give recommendations for making things better.

Comment: @BenjaminW. -- that worked perfectly with single element, can you tell me how to manipulate if we have multiple member elements, how we could do if teamName key equals Developers, then insert the element, otherwise ignore